# Angular opt out of Interceptor behavior

Tags: angularjs, cross-cutting-concerns

In my angular app, I'm looking for a way to handle all server response errors (with a popup box showing an error message) but allow a controller to opt out of this behavior and do it's own error handling if needed when calling a $resource.

I was planning to just use an interceptor and have it handle all errors. Something like

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
    return { 
        'responseError': function(rejection) {
            displayMessage(rejection);
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    };
});
```

Then from the controller, if I call

```
$scope.widget = WidgetResource.get();
```

and the server responds with a 401 error, the user would be shown an error message saying they are not authorized.

But it occurred to me that sometimes a controller may want to handle error responses on it's own (namely, a better way to display the error in the given context). What would be a way that it could opt out of what the interceptor is doing?

Alternately, maybe interceptors is not the way to go for this. What else could I use to handle this cross cutting concern and allow opting out?

Comment: I realize that this question is old, but did you find a good strategy for this? I have a similar need (in Angular 12) to discriminate some requests in an interceptor.

Comment: @Superole Sort of. In AngularJS there wasn't a way, but in Angular, you can use a decorator. It's not trivial so I can't give a full explanation here, but we created an `@ErrorPopup` decorator which will show a popup error when a wrapped method that returns an rxjs Observerable throws an error. So it's really an opt-in rather than opt-out strategy. But it still has the benefit of not having to manually handle errors in the code everywhere.

Comment: @Superole You could also potentially add metadata to an http request and have the interceptor pick that up and skip the normal error handling logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use interceptors to handle errors which are not context specific. We've found it to actually be a good practice. Something like a session timeout(401) or an internal server error(500) are errors that can be handled by your interceptor. While context specific errors are better handled in their respective service callbacks.

You can differentiate based on [HTTP status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) in the following way:

```
function responseError(rejection) {
        switch (rejection.status) {
          case 401:
            //handle unauthenticated request
          case 500:
            //Oops something has gone wrong due to an internal server error
          default:
            break;
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
```

Upon `$q.reject(rejection)` the control is forwarded to the error handler of the respective $resource instance. So in the above example, a 404 from the server will be forwarded to your respective controller or service's error handler.

Comment: I see what you're saying about leaving context specific errors to be handled by the code that understands the context. I'll think about that. The problem I'm really trying to solve is making sure that we're not duplicating the same error handling code (displaying the message to the user) every time we use a $resource.

Comment: If you put it in the interceptor, you wouldn't be duplicating. Right? Eg. in case of an unauthenticated user, you would set the error message in some shared service in the interceptor itself.

Comment: Right, so a better example would be that 99% of the time the server returns 400 Bad Request, I show the same popup with whatever the error message is, but 1% of the time I don't want a popup for the error - I want to display it inline. Is there a way for the controller to say "Hey interceptor, ignore this call I'm making" or something to that effect. If I were using aspectj in java, I would intercept on an annotation to say, "intercept all resource calls unless it has a @DontDisplayMe annotation."